# Slideshows in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I have tried making a slideshow in js and its not working, all I get is the images displayed on the screen in order and the next and previous links just send me to the top of the page. I can't work out why, i know solutions that do work but I don't understand why this solution is not working. There are many solutions I have found online that are very similar to this one and they work, yet this one doesn't, I have only recently started js so I imagine its something silly I have missed. Here is the HTML: (edit: moved the  to the bottom of the html body)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/mainPageStyle.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color:white">
    <div id="titleLogo"><h1>Custom Motorbikes</h1></div>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Full ride list</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Custom ride</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- front page slideshow: -->

    <img src="images/bikePerson.jpg" class="slides" style="width:100%" />
    <img src="images/bikePersonCountry.jpg" class="slides" style="width:100%" />
    <img src="images/bikeRoad.jpg" class="slides" style="width:100%"  />

    <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(1); return false;">Next Slide</a> <br/>
    <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(-1); return false;">Previous Slide</a> 


    <!-- front page slideshow -->
<script type="text/javascript" src='JS/slideshow.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the js:

```
var imgPos = 0;
var changeImage(0);                     //called so that images(except first one) are hidden intially
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");  //creates an array, and fills it with all images with 'slides' class
var arrayLength = imgs.length;

function changeImage(x) {
    var i = 0;                      //used for counting through 'for' loop
    imgPos += x;                    //x will be either -1 or +1

    if (imgPos > arrayLength){      //if user goes beyond last img
        imgPos = 0;                 //go to first img
    }
    if (imgPos < 0){                    //if user goes before first img
        imgPos = arrayLength;       //go to furthest img
    }
    for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        imgs[i].style.display = "none";     //this hides all the images
    }
    imgs[imgPos].style.display = "block";   //this then displays the image we want to see

    return false;
}
```

Here are the errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(…) slideshow.js:22
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined(…)

Comment: What about the slideshow isn't working? "Its not working" isn't very helpful as to what isn't working.

Comment: Make sure your javascript runs after the html has loaded. Usually you can move your script tag to the bottom of the html body to ensure the img tags exist before your script runs.

Comment: LIke @thgaskell says your js is running before your html, so `document.getElementsByClassName("slides");` is finding nothing because the DOM has not yet loaded.

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1 (Move the js to the bottom)

This will run after all of you dom has loaded.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/mainPageStyle.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color:white">
    <div id="titleLogo"><h1>Custom Motorbikes</h1></div>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Full ride list</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Custom ride</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- front page slideshow: -->

    <img src="images/bikePerson.jpg" class="slides" style="width:100%" />
    <img src="images/bikePersonCountry.jpg" class="slides" style="width:100%" />
    <img src="images/bikeRoad.jpg" class="slides" style="width:100%"  />

    <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(1); return false;">Next Slide</a> <br/>
    <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(-1); return false;">Previous Slide</a> 


    <!-- front page slideshow -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src='JS/slideshow.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

## Method 2 (add document ready)

This will trigger the dom loaded event after your dom is loaded.

**Note:** You can not assign a function to a var `var changeImage(0);` You can assign the result of a function to a variable though: `var myVar = changeImage(0);`

```
var imgPos = 0;
var imgs = [];

function changeImage(x) {
    var i = 0;                      //used for counting through 'for' loop
    imgPos += x;                    //x will be either -1 or +1

    imgPos = imgPos + 1 > imgs.length ? 0 : imgPos;
    imgPos = imgPos < 0 ? imgs.length - 1 : imgPos;

    for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgs[i].style.display = "none";     //this hides all the images
    }
    imgs[imgPos].style.display = "block";   //this then displays the image we want to see
    console.log(imgs[imgPos])
    return false;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
    imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img.slides");  //creates an array, and fills it with all images with 'slides' class
    changeImage(0);                     //called so that images(except first one) are hidden intially
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the solutions, I have tried them both, but still get the same problem

Comment: oh yeah that vars not meant to be there

Comment: for the links try using `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: the alerts that i put in now show! so i know the js file is running, and these are the errors i get:   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(…) slideshow.js:22           Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined(…)

Comment: the "javascript:void(0);" has stoped the links sending me to the top of the page, but all the images are still on the page etc

Comment: Try changing `getElementsByClassName('slides')` to `querySelector('.slides')`. **Note** the dot prepended to the word `slides`

Comment: I see what you've done, I added alert("test1") into the top just below the vars, and that alert popped up, i added  alert("test2") inside the function and that popped up but the alert("test3") i placed under the ocument.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {  section did not pop up, does that help?                 along with this error in inspector: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at HTMLDocument.document.addEventListener.event (file:JS/slideshow.js:27:23)    slideshow.js:27

Comment: Okay I was able to get this working in my browser, check out the update.

Comment: it works! im unsure as to what the problem was though? could you explain it?

Comment: I believe the core issue was that you were going above the number of items in the array. and when you set the style to block it was one out of range.

Comment: ah okay, thank you! I have made many errors I can see in this, looks like i'll need to learn more before I can attempt this sort of thing